# Problem on product space of Sorgenfrey line.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ be Sorgenfrey line, $(\mathbb R^2,\tau_1):=(\mathbb R,\tau)\times (\mathbb R,\tau)$. Let $L = \{(x, y) : x, y\in\mathbb R^2, x + y = 0\}$. Show that the line L is closed in the
>   euclidean topology on the plane and hence also in $(\mathbb R^2,\tau_1)$.

I have already shown that L is closed in the euclidean topology, but I can't see how I can proceed to the "hence" part. Please give me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: The Sorgenfrey plane is a finer topology that the Euclidean plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology of the euclidean plane is weaker then the topology of the sorgenfrey plane. 
(  The topology of the euclidean plane is a subset of the sorgenfrey plane topology)

you showed that $\mathbb R -L$ is in the topology of the euclidean plane, then it is also in the topology of the sorgenfrey plane.

hence L is closed in the sorgenfrey plane.